# How to change programmatically change name server using php

Tags: php

I have a website that receives occasional but predictable traffic spikes and my website crashes or slows down. Is it possible for me to change the name-servers programmatically using php or any other language so that the server changes after the traffic touches a certain peak. I am using a godaddy-windows hosting. And I do not want to use cloud computing.

Comment: What do you want to change the name servers to? You realise that dns changes can take as much as 48-hours to replicate, not much use for quickly handing spikes in performance

Comment: You might do better to install an Apache module that ignores users who make excessive requests. That said, maybe you just need a better server? Are you on a VPS/dedicated server?

Comment: oh,thank you I did'nt know that. Is there no ways to distribute traffic between 4 different godaddy hosting servers

Comment: my traffic is non-US hence generates lesser revenues hence VPS/dedicated is out of the picture

Comment: is there any way to load balance these servers?

Comment: Please don't use `code formatting` for emphasis.  In fact, please don't add random emphasis to your questions, it's very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to have much luck because the load balancing stuff happens before PHP like apache. You probably will have to upgrade.

You would have to use something like a load balancer on a proxy that distributes traffic before it hits your server. Its very tricky to do and its almost impossible through a godaddy like host because you can't customise anything on a VPS.

Comment: So I should either go for cloud or have a dedicated huh?

Comment: Yea, you aren't going to get anything that can deal with huge traffic that is a VPS. What kind of traffic are you getting?

You have to get dedicated private hosting, or set up your own.

Comment: don't forget you can also optimise your code to simply be quicker :)

Comment: I'm getting my traffic mostly from south-asia hence ad revenues are low so dedicated will give me a loss. So Amazon cloud won't work?

Comment: If ur revenue is low maybe change ur ad positioning so u get a higher conversion.

Otherwise amazon might work - but its still depends on a lot of different factors. If you get big spikes then you need something sophisticated to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just change nameservers for load balancing (CDNs are based on that principle, but they are implemented on the DNS, since changes need time to propagate). You could pay for more resources and balance them using a proxy, but a better solution is to move your app to Amazon AWS, Google App Engine or a similar cloud based service: they handle load balancing much more efficiently, and that's what you need for occasional spikes (otherwise you end up paying for horsepower you only use occasionally)

Comment: You're welcome. Note I wrote CMS instead of CDNs, in case you were confused about it (don't know what I was thinking ^^')

Comment: its okay I understood(i make the same mistake sometimes)